# Should I go for an interview even if I will probably not take the job?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-change

I work in tech and like many others, I get daily recruiting emails/invites from LinkedIn. I am 90% happy at my current job. (The missing 10% is because management in my team is really stingy when it comes to promotion and pay raise, not the case in other teams though.) So usually I just ignore these emails. But recently, I have been thinking maybe I should take these interviews. Because of the below factors:

1. Maybe the job will make me 100% happy.
2. To keep my interviewing skills sharp.

But there are also risks:

1. If my current company finds out, that won't end well for me.
2. Burning future bridges? Say if I pass the interview but don't take the job. I probably won't be able to apply again in the future.

I like to know what others do in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Just attend the interview. Don't think about whether you will take the job or not before the interview. If you learn to decouple things like that and do things one at a time, there won't be any ethical dilemma.

Comment: If #1 is actually true (that you don't even feel like you can do an interview) then that is a problem, whether or not you intend to take an offer.

Answer (score 3):

If you find the advert for the role interesting and worth considering why not go for the interview

You mention the "risks"

> If my current company finds out, that won't end well for me.

This is not true. For a start the company is very unlikely going to find out. Even if they do it will not matter. It is reasonable for people to do what they want in their free time and it may even be a benefit. They may ask why and give you an opportunity to tell they why you are not 100% happy

> Burning future bridges? Say if I pass the interview but don't take the
>   job. I probably won't be able to apply again in the future.

If you pass the interview and get an offer but turn it down, it means they are interested in you. If at a later date you reapply to the company then the job on the table will be different (project etc) and also people know that circumstances change over time. If they was interested the first time around they will probably still be interested next time.